# Keeping image in div filled and in aspect ratio while display is flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have a div withimages inside, so I am using `display: flex;` for the div. And, I want the images to fill in the div/screen and not stretch it so user can see it clearly.

Here is my sample css code

```
div {
        --n: 1;
        display: flex;
        align-self: center;
        margin: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: calc(var(--n)*100%);
        transform: translate(calc(var(--i)/var(--n)*-100%));
    }

 img {
        width: 100%;
        width: calc(100%/var(--n));
        user-select: none;
        pointer-events: none
    }
```

Here is my html code

```
<div>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514117445516-2ecfc9c4ec90?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=0e0b58fcf67fa6e8a010322d617e39af' alt='Mountain massif, sunbathed, partly covered in show.' />
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510325805092-2951ab330b7d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=017cf46443f4821a375c20e8c68e37f0' alt='Tiny bird with pale brown, orange and white feathers in an evergreen tree.' />
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514848567240-a81cb051807a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=3a0e476ab712db0eb68ab121a21c54de' alt='Close-up of yellow rose opening up.' />
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465408522361-a6f502298219?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=7a6bd1244c42d1dbd3984a4c13981666' alt='Fast and foamy creek in the middle of the forest.' />
     <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503843778847-2b8bdce2ed3d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=d547781176ce182eeeb7303bac05abf4' alt='Fluffy little tabby with blue eyes climbing up a tree.' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understood what you want but as far as I can see this should to the work if I understood clearly.
Try this:

```
 img {
        width: 100%;
        width: calc(100%/var(--n));
        user-select: none;
        pointer-events: none
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **`align-items: center;`** to prevent the stretch. Alternatively you can also use `align-items: flex-start;` or `align-items: flex-end;` as well.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    --number-of-images: 5;
    width: calc(100% / var(--number-of-images));
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514117445516-2ecfc9c4ec90?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=0e0b58fcf67fa6e8a010322d617e39af' alt='Mountain massif, sunbathed, partly covered in show.' />
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510325805092-2951ab330b7d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=017cf46443f4821a375c20e8c68e37f0' alt='Tiny bird with pale brown, orange and white feathers in an evergreen tree.' />
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514848567240-a81cb051807a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=3a0e476ab712db0eb68ab121a21c54de' alt='Close-up of yellow rose opening up.' />
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465408522361-a6f502298219?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=7a6bd1244c42d1dbd3984a4c13981666' alt='Fast and foamy creek in the middle of the forest.' />
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503843778847-2b8bdce2ed3d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=d547781176ce182eeeb7303bac05abf4' alt='Fluffy little tabby with blue eyes climbing up a tree.' />
</div>
```